# Selecting a Table View Cell programmatically from another view controller

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, tableview, segue

I haven't coded this, but I am wondering if it is even possible and how it can be done. Let's say I am on VC1. If I press a button on VC1, I want to be taken to VC2, which has a table view, and then have it automatically select the first cell and segue to a VC3. Anybody with experience of doing this.

Comment: You want to animate this full behaviour..?

Comment: Why does VC2 need to be involved in this?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is more of a conceptual question, yes, this can be done. I've worked on an app where the feature required animating through multiple levels of table views programmatically using `NSNotification`'s. Essentially, you can just have a shared method that is called from `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` that you would call directly to "select" the table cell and do whatever the default action was.

Let me know if this answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

Yes It can be done.There can be many ways, One way is this -

1.In Your viewDidAppear of VC2 have this lines -

```
override  func viewDidAppear() {
  super.viewDidAppear()

  let rowToSelect:NSIndexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 0)

  tableView.selectRowAtIndexPath(rowToSelect, animated: true, scrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPosition.None)

  self.tableView(tableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath: rowToSelect)
}
```

2. In your tableView method didSelectRowAtIndexPath -

   ```
   func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if indexPath.row == 0 {
        self.presentVC3()
    }
   }

   func presentVC3() {
   //Initialize VC3
   // And Segue to VC3
   }
   ```

Comment: This would certainly work but you'll need to be careful in the VC3 code since it will now be potentially presented by two different controllers. In the scenario I've described in my answer, we needed to have the code for VC2 execute as if the user had tapped the cell. Taking these concerns into consideration, this answer could be the solution.

Comment: Why VC3 would be presented by two different controllers, its clearly mentioned in question that VC3 would be presented from VC2, after selection of 1st cell.